# Add 2d plot on an arbitrary plane (in 3d)

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to plot a function (2d plot) with pgfplots such that the plot is drawn on given plane (say $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 = b$) specified before. The 2d coordinate system should be drawn on the plane as well.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%Define plane
\definePlane{E}{3*x + 4*y + 5*z = 6}
\begin{axis}[canvasPlane=E]
\addplot gnuplot {sin(x));
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you would also need to provide the position of the origin on the plane. I'm not sure it is available out of the box,  but it should be possible to define coordinate transformations to get something like this.

Comment: See "4.21 Symbolic Coordinates and User Transformations" in the `pgfplots` manual.

Answer (score 1):

If your camera is located at (3,4,5) and looking toward the origin, here is what you will see:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {sin(\x r)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your camera is at (10,0,0) and looking toward the origin, here is what you will see

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[cm={.6,0,-.57,.71,(0,0)}]
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {sin(\x r)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your camera is on the xy-plane, rotating around the z-axis, looking toward the origin, her is what you will see

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\foreach\i in{10,20,...,360}{
    \tikz{
        \path({sin(\i)*.7*207pt},0cm)++({cos(\i)*120pt},0cm)+(-8cm,-1cm)+(8cm,3cm);
        \begin{scope}[cm={cos(\i),0,.7*sin(\i),.71,(0,0)}]
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot {sin(\x r)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The rest is high school math.