# GIS layer maps from .dat files and not figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to make this figure [Stack figures in horizontal plane in 3D rectangular shape without loss of quality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171998/stack-figures-in-horizontal-plane-in-3d-rectangular-shape-without-loss-of-qualit) .

With a modification he plots each layer with a specific .dat. Can you do it? How I do?

Plot the .dat individually as well as below. But I want to plot several .dat in a figure how to example .

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,filecontents}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
          xlabel={$x$ [m]},
          ylabel={$y$ [m]},
         colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (white);color(1cm) = (black)},
  point meta min=0,
  point meta max=0.00000000006,
  view={0}{90}]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,samples=100]
 table[x index=0,y index=1,z index=4] {heat.dat};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You have a .dat example in the dropbox link.

x,y,z,t,TEMP
https://www.dropbox.com/s/647oes7syhx6xav/heat.dat?dl=0

Thank You ;)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you provide the DAT files by editing the question? Then we have an idea *what* you want to plot and how this could be achieved. Thanks.

Comment: Many people are going to be reluctant to download files of unknown provenance from DropBox, visit links to see what you want, collect bits here, there and everywhere just in order to see if they might be able to help. Make it easy for people to help you: make sure everything people need to decide is in the question.

Comment: I don't see why https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172294/ doesn't answer your question. That explains how to construct the very thing you say you want to draw. There won't be any loss of quality if the plots are PDFs when included in the stack. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry for put link and dropbox here. How to work in linux I don't remember of problem with virus. The next post I take care with this.
Well, I work many data. I want reduced the error for choice of the case for not mix cases and cause a one result with error. In the case of the example is teaching take a figure fineshed and put in the graphs.
What I want is read the data and create all figure and only script.
I resolved this problem with two scripts, but is hard manipulation and for me the graph is not the best. Later I plan to post my solution for problem. 
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not 100% sure if I have understood your question. I interpret it
as: You want to stack multiple `axis` environments which contain data from
different DAT files, right? If so, please have a look at the following code
which is done with PGFPlots only.

I used some data which can be downloaded from the web which show the
temperature anomalies. To have a better idea *where* they are, I also added
a world map to the plots which can also be downloaded.

Because of the large data sets, it is required to compile with LuaLaTeX. For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% data from <https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/maps/> using the settings
%   Data Sources:
%       Land: GISS analysis
%       Ocean: ERSST_v4
%   Map Type: Anomalies
%   Mean Period: Annual (Jan-Dec)
%   Time Interval: Begin = End: 1975, 1985, 1995, 2005
%   Base Period: Begin = End: 1990
%   Smoothing Radius: 1200 km
%   Map Projection: Equirectangular
% World map from <https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_V2.0.svg>
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % because I want to use a nice colorbar suitable for this task I load the
    % `colorbrewer' library of PGFPlots
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colorbrewer}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % to use the advanced `colormap' operations use this `compat' level or higher
        compat=1.14,
        % load a suitable colormap ...
        colormap/RdBu-9,
        % ... and reverse its order
        % <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141338/95441>
        colormap={reverse RdBu}{
            indices of colormap={
                \pgfplotscolormaplastindexof{RdBu-9},...,0 of RdBu-9
            },
        },
        % then create and activate a custom colormap
        % here I want a non-uniform colorbar with constant samples
        colormap={CM}{
            of colormap={
                % state which colormap should be used, ...
                reverse RdBu,
                % ... state the target positions of the colors ...
                target pos={-4,-2,-1,-0.5,-0.2,0.2,0.5,1,2,4},
                % ... and don't interpolate between the colors
                sample for=const,
            },
        },
        % create an axis style to use for all of the plots
        my axis style/.style={
%            % if only the plane itself without the labels should be transformed
%            % then uncomment this line
%            % (more information is given below)
%            cm={cos(-60),cos(85),.7*sin(-60),.5,(0,0)},
            width=\textwidth,
            height=0.6667\textwidth,
            %
            xmin=-180,  xmax=+180,
            ymin=-90,   ymax=+90,
            xtick={-180,-120,-60,0,60,120,180},
            ytick={-90,-60,-30,0,30,60,90},
            % except for the first plot we don't want to show the ticklabels
            xticklabels={},
            yticklabels={},
            % so the ticklabels are shown, draw the `axis on top'
            axis on top,
            % give explicit meta data ...
            point meta=explicit,
            % ... and set their corresponding min and max values
            point meta min=-4.0,
            point meta max=+4.0,
            % use constant samples
            colormap access=piecewise constant,
            %
            % ignore the additional header row in the data files
            table/skip first n=1,
            table/x=lon,
            table/y=lat,
            % "missing data" are represented by the number 9999.0000
            % so you can either edit the data files directly and replace these
            % values by "NaN" or you can PGFPlots handle this itself
            % (here I just change all values >1000 which is an unrealistic value)
            table/meta expr={
                ifthenelse(\thisrow{array(i,j)}>1000, NaN, \thisrow{array(i,j)})
            },
            % we have to help PGFPlots a bit on how the data files are organized
            mesh/rows=90,
            mesh/cols=180,
            %
            % before plotting the acutal data fill the whole plot area with a
            % color which will represent missing data
            execute at begin axis={
                \fill [black!30] (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
            },
            % on top of the data we want to show the world, so we have an idea
            % *where* the temperature anomalies are and use the downloaded map
            % which is mentioned in the top comment.
            % To avoid an error regarding graphics extension I renamed the file
            % from its original name "2000px-World_V2.0.svg.png".
            % (Of course we could also "use" the SVG file, but that would
            %  need some more work, but isn't the point in this example.
            %  You will find a lot of useful hints on how to do this on TeX.SX
            %  e.g. <https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099>)
            execute at end axis={
                \addplot graphics [
                    xmin=-180,  xmax=+180,
                    ymin=-90,   ymax=+90,
                ] {2000px-World_V20.png};
            },
        },
        % create a style for the coordiante transformation of the plots.
        % Thus, there is only one place where you need to put changes, if needed.
        % (More details/comments will be given below before the first `scope')
        /tikz/transformed cs style/.style={
            cm={cos(-60),cos(85),.7*sin(-60),.5,(0,0)},
        },
    }
    % define a macro that stores the offset between the different stacked plots
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\offset}{20ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % change the view of the plane where also the labels are transformed.
    % (not sure if done right, but it seems to be not totally wrong.
    %  To get an impression on how it works look at
    %  <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369495/95441>)
    % If only the plane itself and not also the labels should be transformed,
    % you can give the argument directly to the `axis' environment (see the
    % commented line above)
    % We do it in scopes so stacking the plots on top of each other can be done
    % using the non-transformed coordinate system
    \begin{scope}[transformed cs style]
        \begin{axis}[
            % load the above created style
            my axis style,
            % the first plot (only) shall show the axis labels ...
            xlabel=longitude,
            ylabel=latitude,
            % ... ticklabels
            xticklabels={180W,120W,60W,0,60E,120E,180E},
            yticklabels={90S,60S,30S,0,30N,60N,90N},
            title=1975,
            % name the plot to later use the "node" to set the offset coordinate
            name=plot 1,
        ]
            \addplot [surf,shader=interp] table {1975.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

        % give a coordinate at the place where the next stacked plot should be placed.
        % (Because we are outside the transformed coordinate system here, this is
        %  quite easy to accomplish.)
        % Here we want it to be placed vertically above the "lower" ones with the
        % given offset
        \coordinate (p1) at ([yshift=\offset] plot 1.south west);
    % again start the scope ...
    \begin{scope}[transformed cs style]
        \begin{axis}[
            % ... and load the style
            my axis style,
            title=1985,
            name=plot 2,
            % state, where the plot should be placed. Therefore we use the
            % above created coordinate
            % (the default `anchor` is `south west', so there is no need to
            %  state it explicitly)
            at={(p1)},
        ]
            \addplot [surf,shader=interp] table {1985.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

        \coordinate (p2) at ([yshift=\offset] plot 2.south west);
    \begin{scope}[transformed cs style]
        \begin{axis}[
            my axis style,
            title=1995,
            name=plot 3,
            at={(p2)},
        ]
            \addplot [surf,shader=interp] table {1995.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

        \coordinate (p3) at ([yshift=\offset] plot 3.south west);
    \begin{scope}[transformed cs style]
        \begin{axis}[
            my axis style,
            title=2005,
            name=plot 4,
            at={(p3)},
        ]
            \addplot [surf,shader=interp] table {2005.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

    % Below the first plot we want to place the `colorbar', which was/is used
    % for all the plots. Because we don't want it to be transformed, we create
    % it separate from the plots (again)
    \pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[
%        % because we didn't change the `colormap' inbetween we don't have to
%        % load it again
%        colormap name=CM,
        % again we state the point meta min and max values, ...
        point meta min=-4.0,
        point meta max=+4.0,
        % as well as that we want to
        colormap access=piecewise constant,
        % We want a horizontal colorbar ...
        colorbar horizontal,
        % ... and to show up as "legend".
        colorbar as legend,
        colorbar style={
            % In addition we want it to be placed vertically below the
            % north west corner of the plot ...
            at={(plot 1.below south west -| plot 1.north west)},
            % and state its `width'
            width=0.75\textwidth,
            xlabel=$\Delta T$ / K,
            % also we want the ticklabels to be smaller and show with one
            % decimal figure
            ticklabel style={
                font=\footnotesize,
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    fixed,
                    fixed zerofill,
                    precision=1,
            },
        },
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Hi,
You understood very well my question.
Your solution is easier. 

Thank you for your dedication to making such a complex code for my question. I believe it will be useful to more people.
My solution was pretty confusing. I'll post only the final graphic.